# undefined method with() laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to call a view from a middleware, but I am getting this error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::with()

**Middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\Readdb;

class Adminlogin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (!$request->session()->has('userid')) {
            $db = new Readdb();
            $admin_theme = $db::get_setting('admin_theme');
            $data = array(
                'title' => 'My App yo',
                'Description' => 'This is New Application',
                'author' => 'foo'
            );

            return response()->view('admin.auth.login')->with($data);
        } else {
            return response()->view('admin.dash');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

**View File**

```
{{Session::get('name')}}
```

Comment: simply use return view('admin.auth.login')->with($data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `with()` with `response()`, do it like this:

```
return view('admin.auth.login')->with($data);
```

> For reference - see [Laravel Response Redirects with Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirects)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was simple :P